# Why can't により be used with "concrete, tangible objects"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, nuances

According to "A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar" p. 297, により/によって can be used as "a particle that indicates means"

> その問題は話し合いに{よって/より}解決出来るはずだ。
> We should be able to solve that problem by means of negotiation.

But,

> However, when the instrument is a concrete, tangible object *ni yori* cannot be used as in
> (3) 漢和辞典に{よって/*より}知らない漢字を調べる。

Is this correct? Is there any reason for this?

Comment: As you knew, both 辞典によって調べる and 辞典により調べる are almost equally unnatural. In other words, I disagree that book.